# How to increase quantity of array item with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got two tables. Left side containing all items, right side showing the ordered items. (See picture) [image]

What I want to do: 
If an item from the left table is already added on the right table, instead of adding it again, just increase the quantity by one instead. If that's not the case, just add it..

Code:
**HTML**

```
<form id="OrderedItemsWithoutBatch" class="orderedDataWithoutBatch">
<table class="orderFormArticlesTable" style="width: 47%;float: right; font-size: 9pt;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orderedItemsVM" data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
        <tr class="clickable" data-bind="css: { alternate: $index()%2 }">
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalSku"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: MateriaalDescription"> </td>
            @*<td class="onelineData"><input style="width:2em" type="text" /> [pieces] </td>*@
            <td><input class="orderedQty" style="max-width: 15%" data-bind="value: materiaalAantal"/>[pieces]</td>
            <td data-bind="click: function() { $parent.orderedItems.remove($data); }"><a href="#">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var dataTableForm = $("form.dataWithoutBatch");
var orderedItemsTable = $("form.orderedDataWithoutBatch");
var dataReloading = false;
var currentPage = 0;

//viewModel
var viewModel = {
    orderedItems: ko.observableArray(),
    items: ko.observableArray(),
    sortColumn: ko.observable(),
    total: ko.observable()
}

var request = $.post(url, postData);
    request.fail(function () {
        alert('Failed!');
    });
    request.always(function () {
        listItemsParameterInputs.prop('disabled', false);
        $(document.body).removeClass("loading");

        dataReloading = false;

        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    });
    request.done(function (data) {
        viewModel.total(data.Total);
        viewModel.items.removeAll();

        for (var index = 0; index < data.Items.length; index++) {
            var item = data.Items[index];

            if (item.hasOwnProperty("qty")) {
                item.qty = ko.observable(item.qty);
            }
            else {
                item.qty = ko.observable("");
            }
            item.addItem = function () {
                //Check if item is already in the table on the right
                if(viewModel.orderedItems.indexOf(this) < 0){
                    viewModel.orderedItems.push(this);

                }
                else{
                    // Increase quantity by one.
               }
            }
            viewModel.items.push(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using two arrays and removing elements from the second, why don't you use the *same* array, just add qty variable and show lines only if they satisfy `qty()>0`

That way, you could just increment the value of qty by one in the first table with `this.qty(this.qty()+1);` and set the value to 0 in the second when clicking on remove.

Code for your second table should look something like this:

```
<tbody id="orderedItemsVM" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <!-- ko if: qty()>0 -->
    <tr class="clickable" >
        <td data-bind="text: MateriaalSku"> </td>
        <td data-bind="text: MateriaalDescription"> </td>
        <td>
            <input style="width:2em" type="text" data-bind="value:qty"/>
            [pieces]
        </td>
        <td><a data-bind="click: function() { qty(""); }">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

more on the **if** binding at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: I've already finished what I was doing, but thanks for your input however.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just increment the quantity of your observable as follows:

```
...
else {
    // Increase quantity by one.
    this.qty(this.qty() += 1)
}
```